# Why is my system unable to locate libreadline when I'm certain I've installed it?

Tags: package-management, chromebook, rails, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set up my chromebook for development with crouton and ubuntu. I am using the `railsgirls` recipe to install rails and I'm getting stuck at:

```
E: Unable to locate package libreadline
```

I have run the command `sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev` followed by `apt-get update`.

Still, rails installation is quitting at the libreadline problem. I've never had this problem when setting up my environment on other machines, but clearly I'm missing something here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit: Solved.**

Comment: Have you looked at this as yet? https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/15.04

Comment: @amanthethy, could you post an answer

Comment: @Sneetsher I would, but I've no idea what the OP did to fix it. I just linked a guide in hopes it would help!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what worked unfortunately, but the gorails guide worked while the railsgirls guide did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the instructions at [this site](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/15.04) seemed to work for the OP.

I'm guessing this step did the trick:

1. Install dependencies for Ruby:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
   ```